# Jquery tablesorter customize option for sorting

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter. Table sorter having default order like number, special character and alphabets.
I need to sort like **special character** first, **number** and **alphabets**.

Check this URL on 3rd column (animal)

```
jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/325/
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: What special character are you referring to?

Comment: any special character....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4099/ check this URL, animal column... so that u can get idea... here first is number, then special character and then alphabet... But my priority is like special character, number and alphabets....

Answer (score 1):

The default natural sort breaks up the content into blocks for comparison, but these blocks are set by "chunks" of text characters and numbers. When a non-text/numeric character is encountered it doesn't get broken apart.

So, in your demo the values "#Elephant" and "0Zebra" the sort breaks these values as follows:

```
#Elephant => [ '#Elephant' ]
0Zebra    => [ '0', 'Zebra' ]
```

when the comparison is done it sees "#Elephant" is non-numeric, but "0" is numeric, so based on [ascii comparison](http://www.asciitable.com/), non-numerics (alphabetical characters are assumed) values are greater than numerical values; and thus "#Elephant" gets sorted after "0Zebra".

I know you didn't ask for an explanation, but the easiest way to get around this is to change the sorter. Use the simple text sorter instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4112/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textSorter: {
        2: $.tablesorter.sortText
    }
});
```

---

Update: If you want specific sorting, you'll need to re-order the ascii value. I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4123/) which is specific to the data, it only changes the first character.

```
var reorderAscii = function(x){
    if (x === '') { return x; }
    var v = x.charCodeAt(0),
        z = x.charCodeAt(0);
    if ( z > 90 && z < 97) {
        // move [\]^_` to replace ABCDEF
        v = v - 26;
    } else if (z > 122 && z < 127) {
        // move {|}~ to replace GHIJ
        v = v - 52;
    } else if (z > 47 && z < 58) {
        // move 0123456789 to replace KLMNOPQRST
        v = v + 27;
    }
    return z !== v ? String.fromCharCode(v) + x.slice(1) : x;
};

$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'jui',
    headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
    // ignoreCase must = true
    ignoreCase: true,
    textExtraction: function(node, table, cellIndex){
        var t = $.trim( $(node).text().toLowerCase() );
        return cellIndex === 2 ? reorderAscii(t) : t;    
    },
    textSorter: function (a, b) {
        if (a == b) { return 0; }
        if (a == '') { return 1; }
        if (b == '') { return -1; }
        return a > b ? 1 : -1;
    },
    widgets: ['uitheme', 'zebra', 'columns'],
    widgetOptions: {
        zebra: [
            "ui-widget-content even",
            "ui-state-default odd"]
    }
});
```

I forgot to mention that using any other sorter beside the alphanumeric sorter, the empty cell and string cell sorting are ignored. I need to include that in the documentation.

Comment: Excellent ji... Thanks for description, i thought the same on ascii comparsion for ascending... But look this http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4121/.  Now empty space at the top and some of character comes after the number / alphabets.  I have used empty : "bottom" in header.  But it is not working as of now.  Now i m in need of spl character, number, alphabets (lower and upper parallel) and space/empty.  In my application i have to used everywhere not a single column.  Waiting for your reply... Your Idea is appreciated....